# iOS using google MaterialComponents?

Tags: ios, material-components

I'm trying to use the MDCRaisedButton from  MaterialComponents, added it as a pod dependency similar to all my other dependencies, but as I try to import it I get a compile error `Module MaterialComponents not found`

Are there any extra steps I need to take to use this pod?

I noticed in demos they use

```
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Typography', :path => '../../'
```

What does path do? it gives error when i try to run pod update

Comment: Can you show us your podfile? Have you added the source URL at the top of your podfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:path` isn't an addition you would need when using `MaterialComponents` in your own app, and is used for developing on top of local pods. Have a look here for more info: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#using-the-files-from-a-folder-local-to-the-machine

In order to use `MDCRaisedButton` you would need to initially create a Podfile with `pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons'` inside the chosen app target. If you are using swift as your language of development, I recommend also adding `use_frameworks!`. An example Podfile would look like this:

```
target 'Demo App' do
  use_frameworks! # can remove if using Objective-C
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons'
end
```

After that, the import and usage would be:

Swift:

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons

let button = MDCRaisedButton()
```

Objective-C:

```
#import "MaterialButtons.h"

MDCRaisedButton *button = [[MDCRaisedButton alloc] init];
```

More info can be found here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/Buttons

---

As a side note, `MDCRaisedButton` will soon be deprecated and theming an `MDCButton` using the `MDCContainedButtonThemer` is now the best way to get the same raised button style. Therefore the current best practice of doing this is adding to your podfile:

`pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons+Extensions/ButtonThemer'`

And then in your implementation:

Swift:

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons_ButtonThemer

let buttonScheme = MDCButtonScheme()
let button = MDCButton()
MDCContainedButtonThemer.applyScheme(buttonScheme, to: button)
```

Objective-C:

```
#import "MaterialButtons+ButtonThemer.h"

MDCButton *button = [[MDCButton alloc] init];
MDCButtonScheme *buttonScheme = [[MDCButtonScheme alloc] init];
[MDCContainedButtonThemer applyScheme:buttonScheme toButton:button];
```

More info can be found here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/Buttons/docs/theming.md

The added value of using theming and the scheme is that you can customize the button scheme and have that scheme apply to all your buttons at once. Moreover, if you want a certain color scheme and/or typography scheme throughout your app, the theming now allows these schemes to be applied to all of the material components within your app.

Comment: does not work, `no such module` error. All other pods work except MaterialComponents

Comment: I was missing `use_frameworks!` in my pod file, thanks